# How to populate values in multiple select in active admin (using select2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, jquery-select2

I have the following in my active admin form block. Unfortunately I am not able to load selections, even when putting them in manually (as below):

```
f.input :hearing_loss_level, multiple: true, collection: ["Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Profound"], input_html: { value: ["Mild"] }
```

Update:

I think the issue is related to using select2 through https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons

Answer (score 1):

Here's what ended up working for me:

**Admin model**

```
filter :hearing_loss_level_cont, collection: ["Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Profound"], as: :select, label: 'Hearing Loss Level'

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Form Factor Details" do
    f.input :hearing_loss_level, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: ["Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Profound"], input_html: {style:'width:80%'}
  end
  f.actions
  render partial: 'administration/shared/multiple_select', locals: {
    editing: 'form_factor', 
    context: 'hearing_loss_level',
    selected: f.object.hearing_loss_level ? JSON.parse(f.object.hearing_loss_level).reject(&:empty?) : []
  }
end

controller do
  def update
    params["form_factor"]["hearing_loss_level"] = params["form_factor"]["hearing_loss_level"].reject(&:empty?)
    super
  end
end
```

**administration/shared/multiple_select**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $("#<%= editing %>_<%= context %>").select2('val', <%= raw selected %>)
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `as: :select` of active admin to populate select boxes,

```
f.input :hearing_loss_level, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: ["Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Profound"] ,input_html: { value: ["Mild"] }
```

Comment: first remove `multiple: true` and check once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

**in model**:

```
DATA = ["Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Profound"] #whatsoever
```

**and then in activeadmin:**

```
f.input :hearing_loss_level, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: -> { ModelName::DATA }, input_html: { value: ["Mild"] }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Undefined method 'map' for proc

Comment: @Abram : Updated my answer, Please have a look.

Comment: So I think the problem is that I'm using https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons which triggers select2. Perhaps these solutions do not work with select2. Will update question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to define `multiple: true` on `input_html`:

```rb
f.input :users, as: :select, input_html: { multiple: true }
```

But keep in mind that `activeadmin_addons` supports [Selected List](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/select2_selected_list.md) for multiple selects:

```rb
f.input :users, as: :selected_list
```